# Coordinate (0, 0) is 1 pixel off with LibGDX Camera/Viewport

Tags: java, android, libgdx, viewport

Hopefully the title isn't too confusing, but I am new to LibGDX and after hours of searching on Google I finally got the camera and viewport to work, it now properly scales to the screen. There's still one problem, while the Y coordinate at 0 is correct, the X coordinate at 0 seems to be 1/a few pixels off, I am bad at describing, so here's a picture: [Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzqgj.png)

Like I said, I'm new to LibGDX and I am guessing it's a pretty obvious mistake, but here's the code I'm using:

I use these variables:

```
public static final int WORLD_WIDTH = 480;
public static final int WORLD_HEIGHT = 800;
OrthographicCamera cam;
Viewport viewport;
SpriteBatch batch;
Texture img;
```

I have this in the create():

```
cam = new OrthographicCamera(WORLD_WIDTH, WORLD_HEIGHT);
cam.setToOrtho(false, WORLD_WIDTH, WORLD_HEIGHT);
viewport = new FitViewport(WORLD_WIDTH, WORLD_HEIGHT);
img = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
```

I have this in the render():

```
batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined); //Important
```

And further down in render() I have this code:

```
batch.begin();
batch.draw(img, 0, 0);
batch.end();
```

And I have this in resize():

```
viewport.update(width, height);
```

Which gives the result from the picture.

Is there a solution to this problem, do I need to alter a part of the code, add some new lines or is there a smarter way to do a camera/viewport?

I'm looking forward to your answers, thanks in advance.

Cheers!

Comment: You are not using the viewport correctly. Don't use Camera.setToOrtho anymore, and supply the camera to your Viewport via the constructor. Currently your viewport has an internal camera on its own that you are not using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are experiencing is the way it is supposed to be. You are working with a `FitViewport` and a "virtual" resolution. A `FitViewport` keeps the aspect ratio of the given viewport size, while scaling it up or down to fill your game window. If your window does not have the same aspect ratio like the virtual resolution, `FitViewport` will lead to parts of your window being "empty" (that means having only the glClear-color).

Have a look at the [Viewports wiki page](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports), where you can see this behaviour in a more extreme way.

If you don't want this, you can try it with the "opposite" `FillViewport` (no empty areas, but some parts may be cut off because they are "outside" of your window), a `ScreenViewport` (good for UI), or an `ExtendViewport`.

Comment: Hey noone, I knew about that page and read it multiple times, but did not realise how it worked, I tested a few and it solved my problem. I am not to sure what you mean by supplying the camera to my viewport via the constructor, but I'll figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: You can see how to do that in that wiki page. Just `viewport = new FitViewport(800, 480, camera);`.

Comment: I tried that and it works a little, but the origin of (0, 0) is now somewhere halfway in the X and Y and not in the bottom left corner. I am probably blind and can't find how to set it at the bottom left like it was before. Thanks for the help.

Comment: That's the way it is supposed to be and how you want it. (0, 0) is by default where the camera is centered at (middle of the screen). If you want to change that, you have to change the position of the camera. For UI you can do this easily with viewport.update(width, height, true). The last parameter centers the camera moving (0, 0) to the bottom left corner.

Comment: Sorry for my many questions, I understand LibGDX for the most part but the camera stuff was hard for me. It works now, thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

About a year ago I developed a [full LibGDX game tutorial](https://youtu.be/_rVS1zHThZ0) and provided code that was reusable for any game you'd want to create. I included a dynamic Camera which handled the aspect ratio and resolution perfectly. You can take a look at the code for the camera [here](https://github.com/baseball435/SpaceInvaders/tree/master/SpaceInvaders/src/com/youtube/invaders/camera) and determine how it is similar to yours and if there are any things you can do to improve your camera.

Comment: Sorry, but linking to a (quite outdated) external tutorial video of 90 minutes telling him to compare the code is not an answer on his question.

Comment: @noone The camera system code that I linked him to is not outdated and still works great. I told him to compare his code to mine if he'd like to see similarities and differences to determine the issue. Just because it's a year old does not mean it's outdated, don't assume.

Comment: It is outdated, because in that time `Viewport` did not exist yet and it's basically doing what your code does, just your code is not using libgdx for that. Might be interesting and useful to read, and the tutorial is probably also good (didn't check it myself), but it just doesn't answer his (very concrete) question.